# What is the best strategy to avoid processing the same item multiple times?

Tags: python, sqlite

The system I am developing processes items (with a unique ID), at a speed of approximately 1 million per hour. Many of the items it processes have already been processed before, but I don't know which ones.

To avoid processing multiple times the same items, I created a table in SQLite, where I store the already processed IDs. Then, when processing a new item, I query that table to know if the ID was processed before and if it was already processed I discard the item.

The problem is that the solution is very slow, the process is taking almost 10 times longer to process the same amount of data.

Is there any way to configure SQLite to insert the IDs faster?
Is there a better way to avoid processing the same items multiple times?

The application is written in python, and runs n sub-processes in parallel to speed up the whole process.

Comment: Alternatively, first you can get a list of all the IDs that have been processed, then write a query excluding these IDs and work only with the data that was previously unprocessed.

Comment: Is your unique ID part of an index? Depending on how many duplications there are it may be beneficial or detrimental to maintain an index. The expense of maintaining an index scales differently to searching non indexed columns.

Comment: You can use queues to process item only once.

Comment: I guess the main bottleneck is the synchronization between the subprocesses (profiling would be better than guessing by the way). Maybe each process can hold a small set of the recently seen IDs and store it at once in a single commit in the db if a certain size is reached. This means that there may be some items processed multiple times.

Comment: Another option can be a process dedicated to handle the db which can then have a single, central store of the recent IDs which are stored to db from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I'm going to try what @MichaelButscher suggested.